# What is the analogue of the cross ratio in higher dimensions and what role does it play in n-dimensional geometry?

Tags: linear-transformations, projective-geometry, cross-ratio

I know the cross ratio is defined for four real collinear points and for four points in the complex plane. This is an important projective invariant for linear transformations. Is there an analog for general linear transformations in higher dimensions?

Comment: One concept I've seen in the plane is the cross ratio of four points, as seen from a fifth. That's the cross ratio of the four lines connecting each of the four points to the fifth, via the point-line duality. This generalizes nicely to higher dimensions, i.e. $4$ points seen from (the subspace spanned by) $n-1$ others. Would you consider this to be in scope of your question, or is that the wrong direction?

Answer (score 2):

I know this post is old, but anyway, I will provide an answer. Yes, there are analogues of the cross-ratio for $n + 3$ points in $\mathbb{P}_n(\mathbb{C})$, defined using the $n+1$-dimensional volume on $\mathbb{C}^{n+1}$. See for instance formula 3.20 in:

Olver, P.J., Joint invariant signatures, Found. Comput. Math. 1 (2001), 3-67.

It is also a projective invariant and in fact, there is a theorem called the first main theorem of invariant theory, which says that such cross-ratios form a generating set for all projective invariants, if I am not mistaken. You can probably find the precise statement in books on invariant theory (Hermann Weyl has written a classical book on the topic and Peter Olver has written a more recent book). I hope this gives enough clues to guide you, or the interested reader!

Edit: I will provide the definition here, as requested in the comments by @TedShifrin, since probably not everyone has access to the article above. Given $n + 3$ points in $\mathbb{P}^n(\mathbb{C})$, represented by the nonzero vectors $v_0, \dots, v_{n+2}$, let us divide them into a set of $n - 1$ vectors, say the vectors $v_0, \dots, v_{n-2}$, and let us call the remaining $4$ vectors $w_1, \dots, w_4$. So in our example of the subdivision, we can take $w_1 = v_{n - 1}$, $w_2 = v_n$, $w_3 = v_{n + 1}$ and $w_4 = v_n$. One may define the generalized cross-ratio of these vectors with respect to this subdivision, as
$$ \operatorname{CR}(v_0, \dots, v_{n-2}; w_1, w_2, w_3, w_4) = 
\frac{V(v_0, \dots, v_{n-2}, w_1, w_4) V(v_0, \dots, v_{n - 2}, w_2, w_3)} {V(v_0, \dots, v_{n-2}, w_1, w_3) V(v_0, \dots, v_{n - 2}, w_2, w_4)}, $$
where $V$ is a choice of nonzero volume in $\mathbb{C}^{n+1}$. In other words, $0 \neq V \in \Lambda^{n+1}(\mathbb{C}^{n+1})^*$. Of course $V$ is unique up to scaling by multiplication by a nonzero complex number, but the definition of the cross-ratio above is independent of such a choice. And of course, scaling each of the vectors $v_0, \dots, v_{n+2}$ does not affect the RHS in the definition above. So it is well defined.

If you can get a hold of P. Olver's article I have mentioned, I believe he even proves a version of the first main theorem of invariant theory in this case.

Edit 2: A PDF version of the above article can be found in article numbered 77 in the following page from Olver's website: [Peter Olver's Published Papers](https://www-users.cse.umn.edu/%7Eolver/pubs.html)

Comment: For those of us who do not have access to the journal article, could you expand your answer to make it self-contained?

Comment: I no longer have Weyl's book, but his theorems on vector invariants were for the orthogonal and unitary groups. Invariant functions are functions of the inner products, and in the case of the special orthogonal group, the determinant as well. I certainly have no recollection of anything on cross-ratios.

Comment: It seems that Olver's notion of joint invariants is quite new. I don't think any of this goes back to H. Weyl. But I still cannot access helpful information.

Comment: @TedShifrin, I edited my answer and provided the definition of the higher dimensional cross ratio.

Comment: @TedShifrin, Olver mentions that Weyl only briefly mentions this, while Veblen and Young derived the volume cross-ratios (what I defined in the edit) as basic projective invariants, but did not prove their completeness, nor did they discuss minimal generating sets.

Comment: Oh, many thanks for an interesting answer. (+1) I had to use Weyl's theorems on vector invariants for $U(n)$ in my thesis work 45 or so years ago, but I've certainly never explored the area enough. It certainly looks like Olver, with his work on PDE and group invariants, has also seen fit to work with moving frames and the method of equivalence, building on Cartan, Chern, Gardner, and others.

Comment: @TedShifrin, see also Edit 2, please. You can find a PDF version of that article on Olver's website.